# Convert column string to comma separated

Tags: mysql

I have a column data that has data like this:

```
/142//0/
/25//45//0/
```

In my query i would like to see if i can show the data like this:

```
142,0
25,45,0
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why is the data stored in a format you don't want or need? This calls for some clean-up and conversion. As a note, comma-separated values usually go against the principles of relational database design so this may be a problem you should address on a schema level as well.

Comment: Of course its possible, its even quite easy, did you try it yet

Comment: believe me... i know... its so stupid... this is an inherited project... and actually my query is part of a conversion process to a new system and will be stored relationally going forward  and @RiggsFolly i went searching for mysql functions that would do it but couldnt find one.

Comment: Does it have to be done in a query? Or are you also using another programming language

Comment: basically im querying all the data i need in one query and looping through results and inserting properly into the new database (in short going from joomla to wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select REPLACE(firststep ,'/','') From (SELECT REPLACE(columname,'//',',') as firststep From Table) as a;
```

Change columname and table name.